# No detected activities received (ActivityRecognitionClient)

Tags: android

Here's I tried to configure `ActivityRecognitionClient` to get activities but there is no updates... (Checked on Android 10 and 11)

```
class ActivitiesChecker(private val context: Context) {
    private val activityRecognitionClient = ActivityRecognitionClient(context)

    private val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        context,
        1,
        Intent(context, DetectedActivitiesIntentService::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    private val broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val type = intent.getIntExtra(DetectedActivitiesIntentService.TYPE, -1)
            val confidence = intent.getIntExtra(DetectedActivitiesIntentService.TYPE, 0)

            ToastUtil.toastLong(context, "$type, $confidence")
        }
    }

    fun start() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiver,
            IntentFilter(DetectedActivitiesIntentService.TAG)
        )
        val task = activityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(1000L, pendingIntent)
        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            ToastUtil.toastLong(context, "Successfully requested activity updates")
        }
        task.addOnFailureListener {
            ToastUtil.toastLong(context, "Failed requesting activity updates")
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
        val task = activityRecognitionClient.removeActivityUpdates(pendingIntent)
        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            //
        }
        task.addOnFailureListener {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

service

```
class DetectedActivitiesIntentService : JobIntentService() {

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        val result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent) ?: return
        val activity = result.mostProbableActivity

        Log.i(TAG, "${activity.type} ${activity.confidence}")

        broadcastActivity(activity)
    }

    private fun broadcastActivity(activity: DetectedActivity) {
        val intent = Intent(TAG).apply {
            putExtra(TYPE, activity.type)
            putExtra(CONFIDENCE, activity.confidence)
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG = "${DetectedActivitiesIntentService::class.java.name}.DetectedActivitiesIntentService"
        const val TYPE = "type"
        const val CONFIDENCE = "confidence"
    }
}
```

It prints `Successfully requested activity updates` so everything is supposed to work but still no updates

Permissions were added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

and `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` was runtime requested (needs to be requested on Android 29+)